# Add class to previous element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want to add class for the button after another class but it's inside of another div. Take a look at this example.

```
<div class="wrap">
 <button class="one">Click</button>
 <button class="two">Click</button>
</div>
<div class="bottom"></div>

.add-me{
 color:red;
}
```

In here, I want to add to class button one. But it needs to be applied when bottom class appears.(This is a validation message. So I can't style directly to button one.)

I tried with this way. But it only apply for wrapper div.

```
$('.bottom').prev('div').first().addClass('add-me');
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eqhj0vm9/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `$('.bottom').prev().find(':first-child').addClass('add-me');` to select the prev element's first child.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".activate").click(function(){
     $('.bottom').show();
     $('.bottom').prev().find(':first-child').addClass('add-me');
  });
});
```

```css
.add-me {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <button class="one">Click</button>
  <button class="two">Click</button>
</div>
<div class="bottom" style="display:none"> BOTTOM CLASS </div>

<br />
<button class="activate">Activate bottom class</button>
```

Comment: Work like a charm! But there is another problem. My .bottom class in display:none in normal situation. It only appears when validation works. So can I activate this only the bottom in display:block?

Comment: Nope. It will work even the `.bottom` is `display:none`

Comment: I updated my snippet. And added a style `display:none` for `.bottom` and still working.

Comment: That's the problem. Any solution?

Comment: Ohh. got you mean.

Comment: You have to add `$('.bottom').prev().find(':first-child').addClass('add-me');` on where you show the `.bottom` class